# Fixing Nav bar alignment using Flex Css

Tags: css, navigation, flexbox, navbar

I am trying to fix my content alignment on the navigation bar. I made the Navigation bar mobile ready first.

```
.sidebar{
  position: fixed;
  top:0;
  left:-300px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #262626;
  transition: 1s;
  padding 20px;
  text-align: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sidebar.active{
  left: 0px;
}

.menu-options a{
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-decoration:none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 0px;;
  margin: 6px 0px ;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: .5s;

}
```

When the width of the screen reaches a certain size I try to remove the nav icon (hamburger button)  and the image. I then try to use flex box and justify the content to have space in between.

```
@media screen and (min-width:800px){

  .sidebar{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    height: 7%;
    justify-content: space-between
  }


  .menu-options{
    display: flex;

  }

  .menu-options a{

    padding: 10px 22px;
  }
  .social-icons{
    position: static;
    width: auto;

  }

  .social-icons i{
    padding: 10px 22px;
  }



  .nav-icon,
  .sidebar img{
    display: none;
  }

}
```

Here is the HTML

```
        <body>
<header>
     <!--      Nav icon-->


        <!--    Mobile social media sidebar-->
  <div class="sidebar">
    <div class="nav-icon">
      <div class="hamburger"></div>
    </div>
    <a href="#"><img src="images/wheel_img_web.png"></a>
    <nav class ="menu-options">
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Portfolio</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </nav>
   <!-- social media icons     -->
    <nav class="social-icons">
      <i class="fa fa-linkedin" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <span class="sr-only"></span>
      <i class="fa fa-github" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <span class="sr-only"></span>
      <i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <span class="sr-only"></span>
    </nav>
   </div>
 </header>
     </body>
```

My goal is to have the menu options on the left and the social media icons to the right. The menu options seem to center align for some reason. I believe that it is because it still sees the hamburger and the image as an object. I have this assumption because when I remove the nav-icon (hamburger) and the img banner from the DOM it does what I want it to do. What can I do to fix this situation? Also I have included images in this link that might give a better prespective https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yx_VPB-P19rOwf9W66c-jVlJbCaI_04R?usp=sharing  . Thanks

Comment: we also need your html to combine btw those codes and figure out a solution for you

Comment: Without the HTML it's tough to do this, but I'll take a stab. Can you add `flex: none;` to `.nav-icon, sidebar img{ ... }` ?

Comment: @SUB-HDR I apologize I have now included the HTML with a link to give more perspective.

Comment: @Andy Hoffman. Sorry, i have included the HTML with a link to give more perspective I think it might help. I also tried doing what you instructed but it seems to not have worked.

Comment: @NelsonRodriguez You have a parse error in your CSS, on line 9. You're missing a colon after the property name: `padding 20px;` See if that helps.

Comment: @AndyHoffman I fixed it but it seems to still not be working. Confusing isn't it? can i send you my source code so you can take a look?

Comment: @NelsonRodriguez You should create either a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [CodePen](https://codepen.io) and put the link here.

Comment: @AndyHoffman sorry for the delay. Heres a link to CodePen https://codepen.io/nelson4691/pen/OzxMjV  . Please feel free to let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to add the following to make it work (only one line). This forces the flex child, `.menu-options`, to take the most space contextually available.

```
@media screen and (min-width:800px) {
  …
  .menu-options {
    …
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: @NelsonRodriguez Glad I could help. Do you mind accepting my answer? That's how we get rewarded for doing this.

Comment: I'm more than happy to do that for you :) . Is there a way for me to message you. I want to ask you a few questions about your experience in the field, please. Thanks

Comment: Sure thing, @NelsonRodriguez. Please send me a message through my [website](https://andyhoffman.codes/#contact).